# B2C Custom Policy - add button to redirect to another Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible to add a button to a screen on a custom policy, so that if a user clicks on it, they are redirected to the start of a different custom policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible directly through custom policy logic.

You need to add a link to your app using custom HTML, eg myapp.com/launchPolicy2, and put this link on your login page. When the user clicks this link, the user is sent to your app, and the app should start a new authentication flow using the new authority URL (which contains the new B2C policy Id).

Use this guide to add custom HTML:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy